# Проблема при считывании из текстовика и разбиении по пробелам в PHP!

Tags: php

пробелом считает иногда только 2 символа пробела!
применяю функцию file_get_contents, нужно разбить весь текст по пробелам, проблема в том что в текстовом файле есть допустим пробел, а программа не считает его пробелом, как только добавляешь между словами еще один пробел, то разделяет,в чем проблема?

Comment: Код покажите. И переформулируйте ваш вопрос. Не понятно ж нифига :(

Answer (score 1):

сдается мне что там и не пробел, он выглядет как пробел - но символ другой. Встречаолся с такой хренью - назывался от вроде как неразрывной пробел почитай [тут](http://ktonanovenkogo.ru/html/html-new/probely-specsimvoly-mnemoniki-v-html-kode-nerazryvnyj-probel-specialnye-simvoly-html-css-koda.html) и вот  [тут](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CF%F0%EE%E1%E5%EB)

Comment: использовал регулярку и функцию mb_split('\s',$text), заменил на простую explode и все нормально разделилось